# How to detect the orientation mode while launching the app first

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, screen-orientation, portrait

I am developing an app in which I need to provide different activity's background image on different orientation. So I've approached in this way:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setLanguage();
    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 // set background for landscape
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // set background for portrait
    }
}
```

And

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
```

and in `onCreate()` I set the background image for portrait assuming user will launch the app staying in portrait mode.

Everything works fine as when users change their mode, the corresponding background is set and so on.

But if a user starts this app when the phone is in landscape mode, as It is shown the portrait image at the first launch as I assumed before user will launch app in portrait mode.

So how can I solve this problem? In one sentence, **what is the best way to set different background image for different orientation** ? am I in a right track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `onCreate` of your activity you can check for the current orientation using the this

```
Configuration newConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 // set background for landscape
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // set background for portrait
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Here an question arises.. After adding your snippet in onCreate(), Should I remove android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize" to let onCreate() to do this job OR only add your snippet keeping my previous code unchanged? Because in both way, the expected behaviour can be acheived. What is the better way ?

Comment: i think you should keep the `android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"` as is..coz you don't want the activity `onCreate()` to be called when the user changes the orientation with in the same activity.

Answer (score 3):

> In one sentence, what is the best way to set different background image for different orientation ?

Step #1: Delete everything you've done, most notably the whole `android:configChanges` stuff. Ignore the background image for now, and get the rest of your configuration change logic working.

Step #2: Create `-land` versions of the requisite resource directories, for whatever densities of this image that you have (e.g., `res/drawable-land-hdpi/` to match your `res/drawable-hdpi/`)

Step #3: Move the landscape versions into the `-land` directories, naming them the same as their portrait equivalents (e.g., `res/drawable-hdpi/background.png` and `res/drawable-land-hdpi/background.png`)

Step #4: Just refer to common resource name in your `android:background` attribute (e.g., `@drawable/background`)

This way:

- You stick to better configuration-change behavior, and
- Android will give you the correct background at the correct time

Comment: Thanks for your response. :) Obviously this is the best way to do so. I forgot to mention in my question that my background image is not coming from resource/drawable directories, it is coming from external storage like gallery which I've saved into internal storage in PNG format. That's why I thought to do it programmatically.

So, In this regard, is my current approach is good?

Comment: @DeveloperKid: "Obviously this is the best way to do so" -- I kinda liked it. :-) "I forgot to mention in my question that my background image is not coming from resource/drawable directories" -- yeah, that's an important point. "So, In this regard, is my current approach is good?" -- I'd phrase it more as "your current approach is probably the only available option, even though it's scary". I'd use bakriOnFire's approach for determining your starting state.

Comment: I am accepting bakriOnFire's approach as you said and your solution gives the proper approach for different perspectives I would face. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check for orientation in onCreate

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int orientation = display.getRotation();
if (orientation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || orientation == Surface.ROTATION_180)
{
    // Portrait
}
else
{
    // landscape
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Here an question arises.. After adding your snippet in `onCreate()`, Should I remove `android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"` to let `onCreate()` to do this job OR only add your snippet keeping my previous code unchanged? Because in both way, the expected behaviour  can be acheived. What is the better way ?

Comment: remove android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize". CommonsWare is a better solution though.

Comment: Yes, CommonsWare solution is the right approach, But my perspective is quite different as my image is not coming from resource/drawable directory. :)

Answer (score 0):

check orientation changes after setContentView method

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (orientation == 1){
        utility.toast("portrait");
    }else {
        utility.toast("landscape");
   }
```